# Enum with String values?

Tags: android, enums

In Android, is it possible to use a `String` as underlying value of an `enum`?

Or would I have to use `R.string.myString` (an `int` value) as underlying `enum`value and then lookup this integer?

Thanks :-)

Comment: It's not possible to use anything except int.  What's the context?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the name of an enum like so:

```
enum MyEnum { SOMETHING, ANOTHER_THING }

...

MyEnum enum = <either something or another thing>;
enum.name(); // This gets you the string "SOMETHING" or "ANOTHER_THING"
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't heard of something like what you are describing. However, it is relatively simple to program a lookup function:

```
public String lookupMyEnum(myEnum enum)
{

switch (enum)
{
    case val1:
    return "val1";
    break;
    case val2:
    return "val2";
    break;
    default:
    return NULL;
}

}
```

It is fairly standard to do so. Except with, you know, proper indentation.